# Too many login attempts redirect to home in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

When I have too many login attempts laravel redirect me to home page but how to change that to something else?

I am using laravel 5.4.

My login Controller

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

 class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/login';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

  protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

       /*if($this->guard()->user()->confirmed == 0)
       {
        return redirect('/auth/login')->with('status','Your account is not confirmed. Please confirm before login');
       }*/

        if($this->guard()->user()->role == 'admin' )
        {
            return redirect('/adminPanel/adminHome');
        }
        elseif($this->guard()->user()->role == 'doctor')
        {
            return redirect('/doctorPanel/doctorHome');
        }
        elseif($this->guard()->user()->role == 'patient')
        {
            return redirect('/patientPanel/patientHome');
        }
}
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
 {
return redirect('/login');
  }
 }
```

Routes are

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('/auth/login');
    });

  Auth::routes();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `sendLockoutResponse()` method in `LoginController`:

```
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('some/page');
}
```

Comment: still its taking me to home page

Comment: @NidaAkram please show how exactly did you override the method and show the routes from the app.

Comment: Given those too

Comment: @NidaAkram are you sure it's redirected to the home page? Because your home page renders the same `login` view. If you're sure, put `dd('Too much attempts');` as the first line of `sendLockoutResponse()` method. Does it show you the message?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help..
Because `sendLockoutResponse` is at TrottleLogin auth not AuthenticateUsers...

Try to add

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
```

at the top, and extend this:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

into this

```
use AuthenticatesUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
```

And then check again with function from @AlexeyMezenin :)